# Oracle SQL : Getting average for past 3 month and add additional column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table in Oracle and i need to create a view from this table to calculate of the average score for the past 3 months in additional column.

```
Name      YearMonth     Score
Vince     201507         97
Vince     201508         95
Vince     201509         94
Vince     201510         91
Vince     201511         98
Vince     201512         95
Vince     201501         93
```

Expected output:

```
Name      YearMonth     Score   Average
Vince     201507         97      
Vince     201508         95        
Vince     201509         94      95.33 ((97+95+94)/3)
Vince     201510         91      93.33 ((95+94+91)/3)
Vince     201511         98      94.33 ((94+91+98)/3)
Vince     201512         95      94.67 ((91+98+95)/3)
Vince     201501         93      95.33 ((98+95+93)/3)
```

How can I do it using SQL? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, year_month, score,
       (score +
        lag(score, 1) over (partition by name, year_month order by score) +
        lag(score, 2) over (partition by name, year_month order by score)) / 3 average
  from my_table
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a window function:

```
select name, 
       yearmonth, 
       score,
       avg(score) over (order by to_date(yearmonth, 'yyyymm') range between interval '3' month preceding and current row) as average
from scores;
```

The above assumes `yearmonth` is a `varchar` column, otherwise the `to_date()` wouldn't work.

This is not *exactly* what your sample output is, because the first two rows will have an average that is equal to the row's score (because there are no 3 previous months for those two rows). If you really do need those averages to be null, you can do something like this:

```
select name, 
       yearmonth, 
       score,
       case 
         when row_number() over (order by to_date(yearmonth, 'yyyymm')) > 2 then
             avg(score) over (order by to_date(yearmonth, 'yyyymm') range between interval '3' month preceding and current row) 
         else null -- not really necessary, just for clarity
       end as average
from scores;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Just an followup, can the query be modified to past 3 weeks, instead of months? I need one also for weeks, the YearMonth column will be replace by YearWeek column. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @lanthe, just use `interval '21' day` instead. Dmitry's solution would work for three weeks without any change if you have a `yearweek` column.